# Abysmal performance - Hash join takes >80% of query cost in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

This part of the query makes it quite bad, unfortunately can't see a way around, only optimize.

```
update #db  set contents = i.contents
from (select distinct
(select max(ac.contents) from ##dwv d
left join ##calendar c on 1=1
left join #db ac on d.id = ac.id
and c.ReportingPeriod = ac.DateValue and ac.Data_Type = 'ActivePeriod'
where d.ID = dd.id and month_number >= (cc.month_number-3)
and month_number <= cc.month_number) contents
,dd.id
,cc.ReportingPeriod
from #db dd
left join ##calendar cc on cc.ReportingPeriod = dd.DateValue
where  dd.Data_Type = 'ActivePeriod'
)i
where i.id = #db.id and i.ReportingPeriod = #dashboard.DateValue
```

I was trying to merge it first, but wasn't going somewhere fast, and the above puppy came to be.

The Idea is to mark every customer as active in any given period (year, month in format 'YYYYMM') according to a specific algorithm, so for every customer that matches the report criteria I need to have a row which will tell me if he was active (that is: bought something recently).

`#db` is a temp table where I'm gathering all the data that will be later used for aggregates to produce report - large table of several million rows, depending on timeframe:

```
Create table #db
(
     C_P varchar(6)
    ,Data_Type varchar(20)
    ,id int
    ,contents int
    ,DateValue varchar(10)
)
```

`##dwv` is a temp table where I'm dumping the result of a select on a large view (which itself is very slow), holds about 2.4 million rows

`##calendar` is an ad-hoc table which stores every period the report encompasses in same format 'YYYYMM':

```
select CONVERT(char(6), cast(@startdate as date), 112) "CP"
      ,CONVERT(char(6), cast(PKDate as date), 112) "RP"
      ,(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (CONVERT(char(6), cast(PKDate as date), 112)) asc))-1
       as month_number
into ##calendar
from  [calendar].[dbo].[days]
where PKDate between @startdate and @enddate2
group by CONVERT(char(6), cast(PKDate as date), 112)
```

Query plan tells me that the bit `c.ReportingPeriod = ac.DateValue` is the cuplrit - takes 88% of the subquery cost with it, which in turns accounts for 87% of the cost of whole query.

What am I not seeing here and how can I improve that?

Comment: Have you added indexes to your temp tables? Are you sure you should be dumping all of that data into temp tables instead of taking advantage of the existing tables and indexes? Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Be very careful using global temp tables. There are lots of issues with concurrency there. And why a left join with 1 = 1 as the only predicate? Wouldn't that be simpler as a cross join?

Comment: You're doing an update based on a join with a distinct on a result set with a column expression that uses a correlated subquery with on aggregate on the right table of a left join.  
Can you post the definition of your execution plans and all the tables, and explain the business problem you're trying to solve?  It may be somewhat difficult for us to unravel this query.

Comment: @SqlZim - Yes, added the indexes. But may have to re-investigate them. Need to dump into temps because this is a request for report covering multiple years and needs to show various different metrics and dimensions. On sharing plans it may be difficult - proprietary, non-disclosures and like come into play and I'm already dancing on a very thin rope. But thanks for suggestion - will definitely look into it again.

Comment: @SeanLange - normal temp table was being purged too often for my testing to be smooth. Cross join might eliminate some rows, and I need cartesian result for this bit. Unfortunately. This results in 300M rows, but for now no way around that.

Comment: @WesH - now that you re-stated the issue I'm appreciating it yet again. What I'm trying to achieve is a business report that, working on several data subsets and on the level of the individual customer, shows aggregated values across several years (for now one last one, but there's a talk about going as far back as 2004) showing frequency of orders, number of orders, quantities purchased, and various other metrics like age, where they heard about us, location, method used to register and order etc. In other words: a monster. As for posting structure and plans, see comment to SqlZim.

Comment: A cross join is a cartesian product and it will NOT eliminate any rows. Instead of "left join ##calendar c on 1=1" you can simple use "cross join ##calendar c". But as I said, be careful with global temp tables. They will step all over each other with multiple users.

Comment: @SeanLange Ah, I see - cross join won't work if one table is empty, but it will always return cartesian product if both tables contain at least one row each. Slight misunderstanding of `CROSS JOIN` o my part. Global temp is good - I'm inserting into it once daily with separate code and just re-use it in all queries throughout the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash Joins usually mean that the columns used in the JOIN are not indexed.

Make sure you have covering indexes for these columns:

d.id = ac.id
and c.ReportingPeriod = ac.DateValue and ac.Data_Type

Comment: I did that. It initially helped with performance, but not for long, so that's why I've asked the question. But that relapse was due to me code mucking all the time. Once I've had stable beta of the report went and slapped indexes on all temp tables used. Working.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone stumbles here I'll explain what I did to trim down execution time from 32 minutes to 15 seconds.

One, as suggested in comments and answer by [Tab Alleman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42397463/4315699) I've looked at the indexes for the tables where `HASH JOIN` showed on the execution plan. I've also had a closer look at `ON` clauses for the joins here and there refining them, which ended with smaller numbers of rows in results. To be more specific - the inline query fetching the 'contents' value for update now is against source table '#dwv' that joins to a preprocessed '#calendar' table, as opposed to a cross join between two tables and then another join to the result. This reduced the end dataset to bare hundreds of thousands of rows instead of 17 billion, as reported in the query plan.

Effect is that now the report is lightning quick compared to previous drafts, so much so that it now can be run in a loop and it still outputs in more than reasonable time.

Bottom line is that one has to pay attention to what SQL Server complains about, but also at least have a look at the number of rows crunched and try to lower them whenever possible. Indexing is good, but it's not "the miracle cure" for all that ails your query.

Thanks to all who took time to write here - when several people say similar things it's always good to sit down and think about it.